# Change image colors with GD

Tags: php, image-manipulation, php-gd, imagefilter

I want to learn about images manipulation in PHP and write some code to edit photos.

So, I'm reading about imagefilter() function, but I want to edit the collors manually.

I have a little piece of code with imagefilter to do a image sepia

```
imagefilter($image, IMG_FILTER_GRAYSCALE); 
imagefilter($image, IMG_FILTER_COLORIZE, 55, 25, -10);
imagefilter($image, IMG_FILTER_CONTRAST, -10);
```

I want to do the same, but without imagefilter(); it is possible?

I have understood that it may be getting the colors in the image and then change them and re-paint it;

To get the image colors I have this:

```
$rgb = imagecolorat($out, 10, 15);
$colors = imagecolorsforindex($out, $rgb);
```

And this prints:

```
array(4) { 
  ["red"]=> int(150) 
  ["green"]=> int(100) 
  ["blue"]=> int(15) 
  ["alpha"]=> int(0)
```

}

As I can edit those values ​​and integrate them into the picture?

I would appreciate any kind of help: books, tutorials, code pieces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [imagesetpixel()](http://php.net/imagesetpixel) function. Since this function needs an color identifier as third parameter you need to use [imagecolorallocate()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorallocate.php) to create one.

Here an example code which halves the color values of each color:

```
$rgb = imagecolorat($out, 10, 15);
$colors = imagecolorsforindex($out, $rgb);

$new_color = imagecolorallocate($out, $colors['red'] / 2, $colors['green'] / 2, $colors['blue'] / 2);
imagesetpixel($out, 10, 15, $new_color);
```

Now here a simple greyscale filter:

```
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filename);
$image = imagecreatefrompng($filename);
$out = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);

for($y = 0; $y < $height; $y++) {
    for($x = 0; $x < $width; $x++) {
        list($red, $green, $blue) = array_values(imagecolorsforindex($image, imagecolorat($image, $x, $y)));

        $greyscale = $red + $green + $blue;
        $greyscale /= 3;

        $new_color = imagecolorallocate($out, $greyscale, $greyscale, $greyscale);
        imagesetpixel($out, $x, $y, $new_color);
    }
}

imagedestroy($image); 
header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($out);
imagedestroy($out);
```

Be careful with using `imagecolorallocate` inside of a loop, you can not allocate more colors than `imagecolorstotal` returns inside of an single image. If you reached the limit `imagecolorallocate` will return false and you can use [`imagecolorclosest`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorclosest.php) to get the closet color which already has been allocated.

Comment: Note: this code above only changes _one single_ pixel a bit. And you use the jpeg format to save it. This single pixel may not be visible easily due the compression of jpeg.

Comment: I added an example of an greyscale filter.

Comment: @TomiSebastiánJuárez I'm sorry that I'm maybe a bit too direct, but your comment has the quality of "I want to become rich, how can I do it?"

Comment: No, I only need books, tutorials or anything that help me to understans how to make effects in any image.